# Laravel model event won't fire

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5

I'm using ajax to update my model `User`, the ajax part works fine since the data is updated successfully in the database, inside my controller action the update performed by :

```
$user->update($data);
```

**The part that doesn't work:**

I've used `boot`s method `updated` inside my model like :

```
class User extends BaseModel
{
    ...

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::updated(function($model){
            Log::info("updated");
            dd($model);
        });
    }
}
```

The event was never reached I'm not sure why.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to perform an action after the model update but the event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what the manual states with [`update()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates)

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

You need to use `save` to trigger events. Something like:

```
$user->fill($data);
$user->save();
```

This of course is assuming that `$user` is a model and not a query builder instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the function statically:
instead try using

```
self::updated(function($model){
            Log::info("updated");
            dd($model);
        });
```

Comment: Where I've to put this part? it should be inside some function, isn't it?

Comment: just change the word static to self in your current code